# Can't set transparent terminal background in Xubuntu 11.10

Tags: xubuntu

I feel sorry for upgrading to that buggy version. One of the issues is that terminal background, which I configured to be transparent, became solid color, even though it is set to transparent in preferences. How can I get back my transparency? 
Is it due to any libraries missing?

Comment: Look in your Settings Manager, Window Manager Tweaks and check to see if compositing is On

Answer (score 5, accepted):

duffydack is spot on, I just wanted to add a screen shot.

It is under your settings, window manager tweaks

Make sure "Enable display compositing" is checked off (unlike the picture I posted), and you can adjust some other options while you are there ;)

[image]

Comment: I followed this suggestion but my terminal is still a solid color.  I am using the terminator terminal and have the transparency set to .6.